# pouchdb db.allDocs returns id instead of _id

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to do a query with `db.allDocs` and then pass the results (thousands of documents) to `db.bulkDocs` to delete. The function doesn't delete the documents from the database. When I checked the console output of the results from `db.allDocs`, each documents id was `id` instead of `_id`.

```
db.allDocs({
  // include_docs: true, //commented out because i don't need whole doc
  startkey: 'transaction_' + accInfo._id + '_', 
  endkey: 'transaction_' + accInfo._id + '_\uffff'
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log('results.....', result.rows)

  result.rows.map(function (result) {
    result._deleted = true;
  });

  db.db.bulkDocs(result.rows, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
        return console.log('there was an err', err);
     } else {
        console.log(response, 'Documents deleted Successfully');
     }
  });

});
```

The documentation from [here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) states:

> options.include_docs: Include the document itself in each row in the
>   doc field. Otherwise by default you only get the _id and _rev
>   properties.

But i don't get the documents `_id`, i get `id`.

If i set `include_docs: true`, i get the appropriate `_id` but i don't need the whole document and if i return the whole document I have to do the following to make it work:

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  startkey: 'transaction_' + accInfo._id + '_', 
  endkey: 'transaction_' + accInfo._id + '_\uffff'
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log('results.....', result.rows)

  let docs = [];
  result.rows.map(function (result) {
    result.doc._deleted = true;
    docs.push(result.doc)
  });

  db.db.bulkDocs(docs, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
        return console.log('there was an err', err);
     } else {
        console.log(response, 'Documents deleted Successfully');
     }
  });

});
```

Using pouchdb version: 6.0.6

Is there a way to get `db.allDocs` to return `_id` without returning the whole document? Or is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: For passersby: https://pouchdb.com/guides/bulk-operations.html